# Android contacts account

Tags: android, android-service, android-contacts

I create android account to add contacts to my phone. I add contact using ContentProviderOperation, but i don't have my account in options of contact app "contact to display". Do i need implement some special, or add contact in diffrent way?

I create account by exteds AbstractAccountAuthenticator, and create service with setting:

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="com.abc"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also reference an account preferences xml from your authenticator.xml, and make sure that the authority to pass to the ContentResolver (for setSyncAutomatically, setIsSyncable, addPeriodicSync, etc.) is "com.android.contacts", not your custom ContentProvider authority. You will have to do the same in your syncadapter.xml, setting android:contentAuthority to "com.android.contacts". This should be sufficient to display your account.